# Find all the intervals in which $ -x^4 + x + 3 \ge 0 $

Tags: calculus, functions

How do I find all the intervals in which $$-x^4 + x + 3 \ge 0$$?

First of all, I let $f(x) = -x^4 + x + 3$. Then I used the derivative $f'(x) = -4x^3 + 1$ to study its growth.

I used the expression $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ to write $f'(x)$ as the following

$$f'(x) = (1 - x\sqrt[3]{4})(1 + x \sqrt[3]{4} + (x \sqrt[3]{4})^2 )$$

from which I clearly have the solution $x = 1/\sqrt[3]{4}$.

For $4^\frac{2}{3}x^2  + x\sqrt[3]{4} + 1$  we have $\Delta = 4^\frac{2}{3}-4\cdot4^\frac{2}{3}\cdot1 < 0 $ which means that there are no solutions in $\mathbb{R}$.

As $f'(2) < 0$ it means that the function is decreasing on $(1/\sqrt[3]{4}, \infty)$ and increasing on $(-\infty, 1/\sqrt[3]{4})$.

But was thinking about an approach to use Rolle's theorem but to no avail as I won't be able to pinpoint solutions of the equation.

Comment: To get $\ge$, use \ge. Similarly, \le for $\le$. Also, brackets or \cdot are better to use than $*$.

Comment: Modified :) Thank you!

Comment: What you wrote is correct, but does not really help you. What you really need are the (real) roots of the polynomial. Since you have a forth order polynomial and there are no obvious solutions you need to solve for them numerically or use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Ferrari's_solution which isnt too hard for this problem because you do not have a cubic and quadratic term.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the roots of the derivative in a simpler way:

$$-4x^3+1=0\implies x^3=\frac14$$ and in the reals the cubic root is unique.

Now if we evaluate the polynomial at $\dfrac1{\sqrt[3]4}$ we find

$$-\dfrac1{4\sqrt[3]4}+\dfrac1{\sqrt[3]4}+3,$$ which is positive.

So there is a single interval where the polynomial is positive, defined by the two roots, which are on either side of  $\dfrac1{\sqrt[3]4}$. By trial an error, we see that this interval contains $-1$ and $1$ but not $-2$ nor $2$.

The roots do have a closed-form expression, but it is a little masochistic.